# Add columns in certain position to a set of data.frames contained in a list, preferably with mapply

Tags: r, list, function, mapply

I have a set of data.frames on a list, and I would like to add two empty columns in the 4th and 17th position to each of the data frames, so I can later rbind them with others dfs. I need to do it using position because the names are not matching.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y=letters[1:3])
df2 <- data.frame(x = 4:6, y=letters[4:6])
data_list <- list(df1,df2)
```

I think I could use something like this as a base, which I took from another question.

```
data_list2 <- mapply(`[<-`, data_list, 'emptyColumn', value = 'NA', SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

But instead of just adding it at the end, I need to add it on a certain position, let's say on the 2nd, for example.

Also an explanation of what `[<-` does would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I came out with this:

```
data_list2 <- mapply(add_column, data_list, 'emptyColumn'='NA',.after=4, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: Note this is involves using the `dplyr` package

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with `lapply` and `append`. `mapply` will only be useful if you have different vectors of values for `emptyColumn`.

```r
lapply(data_list, \(x) data.frame(append(x, list("emptyColumn" = rep(NA, nrow(df1))), after = 1)))

[[1]]
  x emptyColumn y
1 1          NA a
2 2          NA b
3 3          NA c

[[2]]
  x emptyColumn y
1 4          NA d
2 5          NA e
3 6          NA f
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively using `purrr` and `tibble::add_column()`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y=letters[1:3], z = 1:3, a = 1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 4:6, y=letters[4:6], z = 1:3, a = 1:3)
data_list <- list(df1,df2)

library(purrr)
library(tibble)

positions <- c(4,1)
map2(data_list, positions, ~.x |> 
       add_column(empty_column = NA, .before = .y))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1]]
  x y z empty_column a
1 1 a 1           NA 1
2 2 b 2           NA 2
3 3 c 3           NA 3

[[2]]
  empty_column x y z a
1           NA 4 d 1 1
2           NA 5 e 2 2
3           NA 6 f 3 3
```

Comment: Ah I see your `tibble::add_column()` is the short cut for `mutate` and `relocate`.